# InterpolationOrder for ContourPlot

Tags: plotting

How do I acheive something like `InterpolationOrder` in `ListContourPlot` for `ContourPlot`? My main problem is I want to smooth the contours in `ContourPlot`.

I have some points which I'm going to call data, which is 10,000 points and looks like this:

```
{{24.3,40.0},{29.2,56.0} ... }
```

I create this distance function:

```
D[x_,y_]=(#[[1]]-x)^2+(#[[2]]-y)^2&/@data
```

Now, my function is supposed to count the number of points within a certain distance of any x,y position and divide by the total number of points:

```
F[x_,y_,r_]:=Length[Select[D[x,y],(#<r^2)&]]/Length[data]
```

Now I can plot my function,

```
ContourPlot[F[x,y,5],{x,0,100},{y,0,100}]
```

The problem is my function is not naturally smooth.

I know about `SmoothDensityHistogram` and `DensityHistogram`, but I like the more simple look of smoothed contours.  Can anyone help with this?

Comment: The problem is ContourPlot takes a function. I would use ListContourPlot, but I want to superimpose another plot on top of the contour and I lose the (x,y) information with ListContourPlot.

Comment: Please include an example in your question.  Do not leave us guessing.

Comment: Also, welcome to Mathematica.SE.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using `EuclideanDistance[#,{x,y}]&/@ data` and are instead rolling your own distance function?

Comment: @Verbela: Yes. The reason is I'm not very good with Mathematica. :) Thanks for the suggestion. I will adjust my code.

Comment: One general suggestion: Don't define functions/symbols that start with a capital letter as they might shadow or clash with MMa defined functions and symbols. An example is your use of D which MMa is using for the derivative.

Comment: @szabolcs the function Henry wants to plot is a discrete one, but he wants the steps to be smoothed. Hence, the need for some kind of interpolation.

Comment: @Szabolcs Ah, I see. I didn't go that far back in the edits.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most efficient way to carry out your task, which is to plot a contour map of a *kernel density* of your points, is by converting the points to raster format and using a Fast Fourier Transform to convolve them with a density kernel.  But that takes some work.  If you're willing to wait a few seconds, the whole procedure is (less efficiently) built into *Mathematica*'s `SmoothKernelDistribution` function.

Here is an example taken, with minor changes (to make it more interesting), directly from the [help page](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SmoothKernelDistribution.html):

```
(* Create some data--around 10,000 points--for the illustration *)
data = Join @@ Table[RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[m, {1/2, 1/2}, 0], 1500], 
        {m, RandomReal[{1, 9}, {7, 2}]}];

(* Create a rough (D1) and smooth (D2) density for contouring *)
D1 = SmoothKernelDistribution[data, 0.02]; (* Takes a few seconds *)
D2 = SmoothKernelDistribution[data, 0.5];  (* Takes a few more seconds *)

(* Plot the points and their densities *)
points = ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}}, AspectRatio -> 1];
TableForm[{
  Prepend[
   Table[
     ContourPlot[
       Evaluate@PDF[D, {x, y}], {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, 
       PlotRange -> All, 
       ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"], 
     {D, {D1, D2}}
 ], points]
}]
```

[image: Figure]

Comment: Actually your code runs near instantaneously here.  Did you use a lot more points when you found that it takes a few seconds?  If you don't want to use `SmoothKernelDistribution` because of performance concerns (actually I don't know how it's implemented...), and you'd rather use something FFT based, that's easy to do as well: `ListConvolve[GaussianMatrix[5], 
  BinCounts[data, .1, .1]] // ListContourPlot`

Comment: Thanks.  I don't think `ListConvolve`, as directly applied to the data, does what the OP intends.  You first need to create a 2D array, somewhat as in your reply here, but you don't evaluate the density `F` on a regular grid: you grid the *points* (as sums of indicator functions) and then you could use `ListConvolve` *et al.* with a suitably chosen kernel.  `SmoothKernelDistribution` really bogged down for me when using custom kernels; at one point it ate all my RAM and forced a reboot :-(.

Comment: I see you're using `BinCounts` to rasterize the points, so that's ok: nice, simple solution.  In practice, far more bins would likely be desirable.

Comment: "The most efficient way to carry out your task, which is to plot a contour map of a kernel density of your points, is by converting the points to raster format and using a Fast Fourier Transform to convolve them with a density kernel." <-- Doesn't this require a regular binning?  Is there a way to use the FFT to speed up the convolution when we don't have a function sampled on a regular grid?  Yes, you are right that the `BinCounts` + `ListConvolve` method will get slow quickly as the bin size is decreased.

Comment: It might be worth some testing and benchmarking.  In principle, using sparse matrices, `BinCounts` is just a $O(n)$ operation (time and storage) for $n$ input points.  `ListConvolve`--or at least the FFT equivalent--will need $O(1/h^2)$ storage and $O(-\log(h)/h)$ time for a bin width of $h$.

Comment: I assume smoothing influences the height levels of the plot, for instance, its extreme values, right? So, wouldn't that be an unwanted side effect of creating smoothed contours?

Comment: Yes, it is worth emphasizing that smoothing affects height--otherwise it couldn't possibly change the contours!  Whether this unavoidable effect is "unwanted" depends on whether one is aware of what smoothing does.

Comment: @whuber out of curiosity do you recall what custom kernels caused the system to "bog down"?

Answer (score 6):

I'd say you could solve this problem by evaluating your function `F` on a regular grid and feeding this data to `ListContourPlot` with the `InterpolationOrder` set at an appropriate level.

```
data = RandomVariate[
          MultinormalDistribution[{50, 50}, 150 {{1, 0.8}, {0.8, 4}}], 10000];
dist[x_, y_] := EuclideanDistance[#, {x, y}] & /@ data;
f[x_, y_, r_] := Length[Select[dist[x, y], (# < r^2) &]]/Length[data]
pts = Table[f[x, y, 5], {x, 0, 100}, {y, 0, 100}]; 

ListContourPlot[pts, InterpolationOrder -> 0]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ListContourPlot[pts, InterpolationOrder -> 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The job `ContourPlot` does isn't that bad, by the way:

```
ContourPlot[f[x, y, 5], {x, 0, 100}, {y, 0, 100}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(Yes, I know the plot is rotated with respect to the above ones. I forgot to order x and y in the correct order in the `Table` function)

Comment: +1 The last plot is actually a *reflection*, not a rotation.

Comment: @whuber True, a reflection in the x==y axis.