# Improving ListContourPlot mesh triangulation

Tags: plotting

I have a irregularly placed measurement data. I bring here a small example. I am sorry for that.

> mdata = {{20., 1.6, 0.218084}, {4.02807, 1.71068, 0.227565}, {19.,
>   1.6, 0.240074}, {18.8333, 1.60667, 0.278783}, {17.5, 1.62, 0.406884}, {21.9127, 1.72134, 0.427501}, {16.89, 1.61925, 0.438591}, {7.22189,
>   1.70931, 0.455631}, {16.1132, 1.62516, 0.515403}, {8.51871, 1.68045, 0.524135}, {8.4419, 1.69226, 0.531889}, {9.6625, 1.68612, 0.601701}, {14.1699, 1.63774, 0.639421}, {14.5437, 1.63975, 0.65735}, {13.5583,
>   1.64633, 0.700959}, {11.9613, 1.66151, 0.704242}, {11.276, 1.67761, 0.706502}, {12.9152, 1.65519, 0.718618}, {12.3724, 1.66034, 0.719962}, {12.2406, 1.66432, 0.724829}, {12.9876, 1.6586, 0.734248}, {13.1918,
>   1.65804, 0.750541}, {13.8071, 1.6563, 0.754093}, {13.1619, 1.66528, 0.759312}, {13.111, 1.66365, 0.764214}, {13.2852, 1.67032, 0.787843}, {14.4106, 1.6628, 0.805543}, {22.6391, 1.68181, 0.810923}, {13.9972,
>   1.7042, 0.817875}, {14.8398, 1.66263, 0.818304}, {22.2249, 1.68764, 0.824216}, {19.9883, 1.70148, 0.827452}, {16.1394, 1.66178, 0.840096}, {15.3544, 1.67243, 0.873424}, {15.6949, 1.67557, 0.903093}};

```
ListContourPlot[mdata, Mesh -> All]
```

[image: problematic listContourPlot]

So the data is not so bad, but the *traingulation(?)* of the mesh looks ugly. It seems to be issue with the aspect ration of the data as the fallowing plot looks much better:

```
ListContourPlot[{1, 100, 1} (# - {0, 1.6, 0}) & /@ mdata, Mesh -> All]
```

[image: hack1]

The downside of this trick is, that now I will have to implement the y axes label override in order to show the correct numbers. Is there a smarter workaround?

Weakly related is [Smoothing ListContourPlot contours](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/45519/2036) but it is about data smoothing. I want to show the actual data.

I have the same issue with both *Mathematica* 8&9.

**EDIT**

Here is my attempt using overriding the tick labels.

```
rescaleParams = {1, 100, 1};
dataRanges = {Min@#, Max@#} & /@ (Transpose[mdata][[{1, 2}]]);
tickF[rescaleParam_, min_, max_] := {rescaleParam #, N@#} & /@ 
   FindDivisions[{min, max}, 5];
ListContourPlot[rescaleParams # & /@ mdata, Mesh -> All, 
 FrameTicks -> 
  MapThread[
   tickF, {rescaleParams[[{1, 2}]], dataRanges[[;; , 1]], 
    dataRanges[[;; , 2]]}]]
```

[image]

As I was afraid, it is messy. It is also problematic in the case I want to combine it with some other plots using `Show`. If you made this override method more elegant or at least improve the rounding of the tick labels, it would be appreciated as well.

Comment: Look up `FindDivisions` for choosing tick positions.

Comment: @SimonWoods Thanks! I have reimplemented this thing like so many times. The example is now updated. I still like Belisarius' answer more though. Let's see if he cares to provide any more comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't take it too seriously, it's just a trick:

```
a = ListContourPlot[mdata, Mesh -> All]; 
b = ListContourPlot[{1, 100, 1} # & /@ mdata, Mesh -> All];
gcB = Cases[b, GraphicsComplex[l_, p_] :>GraphicsComplex[{1, 1/100} # &/@ l, p]];
a /. GraphicsComplex[___] :> gcB
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Fancy. Could you comment on possible pitfalls of the method? It can be overlay using `Show` using the 'correct' coordinates, right? atm it seems nicer than the label override I added to the question.

Comment: The method can be simplified to `Show[ListContourPlot[{1,100,1} #&/@mdata,Mesh->All]/.GraphicsComplex[l_,p_]:>GraphicsComplex[{1,1/100} #&/@l,p],PlotRange->All]`.