# Smooth out contour in RegionPlot/ContourPlot

Tags: plotting

I would like to smooth out the jagged edges in the outermost contours in the following plot:

[image: Plot with jagged edges.]

I have data of values as a function of variables (x,y) in the form

```
data = {{{x1,y1},z1},{{x2,y2},z2},...};
```

The figure is produced by

```
data = << "data.dat";
fnct = Interpolation[data];    
RegionPlot[{fnct[x, y] > 2, fnct[x, y] > 100, fnct[x, y] > 140}, {x, 10^-2, 10^1}, {y, 0, 3},MaxRecursion->5]
```

The outer edges seem jagged I guess because the data is not very good there. I need to fit a smooth contour instead. I've looked at some other questions like
[Smoothing ListContourPlot contours](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45519/smoothing-listcontourplot-contours) but that uses ListContourPlot which for me takes ages and produces a bad result even for the original figure.

Any help appreciated.

The data can be found here:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/34796693/data.dat

Comment: The moving average method will damage the data a lot, so I recommend to use Gaussian Filter to do the smoothing, which will primarily get rid of the noises without changing the figure too much.

Comment: I recommend presenting the computation and its result.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First we import the data, which OP is kind enough to leave in his Dropbox for these past 18 months.

```
data = N@Get["https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/34796693/data.dat"];
```

Next we look at the data and notice that it is on a rectangular grid,

```
Dimensions[data]
Dimensions@Gather[data[[All, 1, 1]]]
(* {180901, 2} *)
(* {601, 301} *)
```

This is going to make all the difference here (if it weren't on a rectangular grid than you wouldn't have been able to do a decent `Interpolation` anyway).

The plan here is to apply a [`MovingAverage`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MovingAverage.html) along the rows and columns of the grid.  `MovingAverage` likes to work on matrices or vectors, not lists like `{{{x1,y1},z1},{{x2,y2},z2}....}`, so there are a couple of reshaping steps thrown in here for good measure.

```
npts = 10;
smootheddata = {{#1, #2}, #3} & @@@
   Flatten[
    Transpose[
     MovingAverage[#, npts] & /@
      Transpose[
       MovingAverage[#, npts] & /@
        Partition[Flatten /@ data, 301]
       ]
     ]
    , 1];
```

Now you just do as you were doing before, create an interpolation function then apply `RegionPlot` to it, but now you must be aware that you have a smaller range of gridpoints after applying the averaging.

```
{{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}} = 
 MinMax /@ Transpose[smootheddata[[All, 1]]]
fnct = Interpolation[smootheddata];
RegionPlot[{fnct[x, y] > 2, fnct[x, y] > 100, fnct[x, y] > 140}, {x, 
  xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax}, MaxRecursion -> 5]

(* {{0.0107256, 9.66286}, {0.045, 2.955}} *)
```

[image]

You can see that it is probably fine to just average the rows, but the best results come from averaging both rows and columns.

[image]

Above I've used 10 as the number of elements to average over, but you can get a smoother plot by including more elements.  This will have the effect of decreasing the size of the grid points so you have to choose the best option.  Here are a few values for `npts`

[image]

Comment: Thank you for an informative (if somewhat belated) solution.