# How to find the boundary of a region from a dataset

Tags: graphics, image-processing, smoothing

I have a dataset which supposed to show some regions. For example

```
r1 = Disk[{-0.1, -0.1}, 0.5];
r2 = Disk[{0.7, 0.5}, 0.2];
ran = 0.25; (*random amplitude*)
f[x_, y_] := Which[RegionMember[r1, {x, y}], 1 + RandomReal[{-ran, ran}], 
              RegionMember[r2, {x, y}], -1 + RandomReal[{-ran, ran}], True, 
              RandomReal[{-ran, ran}]]
data = Table[{x, y, f[x, y]}, {x, 0, 1, 0.02}, {y, 0, 0.8, 0.02}]~ Flatten~1;
ListDensityPlot[data, InterpolationOrder -> 0, PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 4/5]
```

[image]

And I want to extract the edges of the `r1` and `r2`.

I try to convert the `data` into an `image` and use `EdgeDetect`.

```
ndat = Length[data]
{zmin, zmax} = MinMax@data[[All, 3]]
Do[If[data[[n, 1]] != data[[n + 1, 1]], ny = n; Break[]], {n, ndat}];
nx = ndat/ny;

imdata = Partition[data[[All, 3]], ny];
imdata = Table[(imdata[[j, ny - i + 1]] - zmin)/(zmax - zmin), {i, ny}, {j, nx}];
img = Image[imdata];

pts = PixelValuePositions[EdgeDetect[img], 1];
pts = Partition[data[[All, 1 ;; 2]], ny][[#[[1]], #[[2]]]] & /@ pts;
ListDensityPlot[data, InterpolationOrder -> 0, PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 4/5,
                Epilog -> {Red, Point[pts]}]
```

[image]

In this way,

1. I cannot isolate the regions - for example, the edges of the circle and the quarter circle in the corner.
2. I cannot find a smooth line for the edges.
3. It does not work very well when I increase the noise (say `ran=0.5`).

How to find the separate edges as isolated lines/lists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can  (1) use `ListDensityPlot` with options `InterpolationOrder -> 1` and `MeshFunctions` to create mesh lines, and (2) use the function `smoothCP` from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/172395/125) to smooth the mesh lines:

```
ClearAll[smoothCP]
smoothCP = Module[{pr = PlotRange @ #,  nF =  Nearest[Join @@ Cases[Normal @ #, 
       Line[a_] :> Transpose[#2 /@ Transpose@a], ∞]]},
   # /. GraphicsComplex[a_, b__] :> GraphicsComplex[ 
       If[Or @@ MemberQ @@@ Thread @ {pr, #}, #, First @ nF @ #] & /@ a, b] ] &;
   
ldp1 = ListDensityPlot[data, InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
   PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 4/5, ImageSize -> 300];
ldp2 = ListDensityPlot[data, InterpolationOrder -> 1, 
   PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 4/5, ImageSize -> 300, PlotStyle -> None,
   MeshFunctions -> {Round@#3 &}, Mesh -> 2, MeshStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red]];

 Row[{Show[ldp1, ldp2], Show[ldp1, smoothCP[ldp2, GaussianFilter[#, {5, 5}] &], 
   PlotRange -> All]}]
```

[image]

> ***Is it possible to extract the contours as separate lists?***

To extract the smoothed lines, you can use

```
lines = Cases[Normal[smoothCP[ldp2, GaussianFilter[#, {5, 5}] &]], _Line, Infinity]
Short /@ lines
```

> {Line[{{0., 0.387454}, << 58 >>, {0.392532, 0.}}],
>    Line[{{0.504121, 0.483339}, << 146 >>, {0.504121, 0.483339}}]}

To get just the coordinates of the two lines, use `Line[x_, ___]:>x` instead of `_Line` above.

Comment: Is it possible to extract the contours as separate lists. I can see the points from `smoothCP[ldp2, GaussianFilter[#, {5, 5}] &][[1, 1]]` but cannot group them as separate lines. I am trying to get a list like `{{{line1x1,line1y1},...},{{line2x1,line2y1},...},...}`.

Comment: @Sumit, I updated with a way to extract the contours.

Answer (score 3):

The following function `extractregion` might be something to start with. First, it smoothes along the third entries in the data set by `TotalVariationFilter`. T`TotalVariationFilter` has the advantage over, e.g. `GaussianFilter`, that it tends to preserve edge jumps, which is really desired here. Afterwards, we interpolate the smoothed data set, plot a `ContourPlot`, extract the contour lines, and convert them to a single `MeshRegion`.

```
extractregion[data_, level_, smoothing_] := 
 Module[{a, n, g, contour},
  a = data;
  n = FirstPosition[Unitize[Subtract[a[[1 ;; -2, 1]], a[[2 ;; -1, 1]]]], 1][[1]];
  a[[All, 3]] = Flatten[TotalVariationFilter[Partition[a[[All, 3]], n], smoothing]];
  g = Interpolation[a];
  contour = 
   ContourPlot[
    g[x, y] == level, {x, Sequence @@ g[[1, 1]]}, {y, Sequence @@ g[[1, 2]]}];
  RegionUnion@Map[
    gc \[Function] MeshRegion[gc[[1]], Cases[gc, _Line, All]],
    Cases[contour, _GraphicsComplex, All]
    ]
  ]
```

This is how it behaves on the provide example data:

```
Show[
 ListDensityPlot[data, InterpolationOrder -> 0, PlotRange -> All, 
  AspectRatio -> 4/5],
 extractregion[data, 0.5, 3],
 extractregion[data, -0.5, 1.2]
 ]
```

[image]

It doesn't close the quarter of the disk in the lower left corner. I don't now an elegant way to do that at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

```
img = Image[Reverse@Rescale[Map[Last] /@ GatherBy[data, First]]];
HighlightImage[img, {Opacity[.6], FaceForm[Red], EdgeForm[], EdgeDetect[img]}]
```

[image]