# Smoothen curve in ListDensityPlot

Tags: plotting, smoothing

I have a list of points of dimensions (150,101) and I am plotting them in a `ListDensityPlot`. I am happy with the command and how the data is represented, but I would really like to smoothen out some curve points (see picture). I tried changing `InterplationOrder` but this had no effect on the graph, other than it changed the colouring a bit. [image]

Basically I would like to smoothen out these points on the blue boundary of the curve so that I no longer have this "seesaw" effect. I would really like to avoid running the computation again since it takes quite a few hours already.

Comment: You can apply interpolation to the original data outside DensityPlot[]

Comment: Could you expand on that please? I tried a simple `Interpolation[data]` but it produces an error which says `Throw::sysexc: Uncaught SystemException returned to top level. Can be caught with Catch[\[Ellipsis], _SystemException].`

Comment: What does the data sheet look like?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [172253](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/172253/38178). What applies to `ListContourPlot` does also aplly to `ListDensityPlot`.