# Rendering PNG images to spline curves

Tags: image-processing, splines

I found something interesting on this page ([Generic contour smoothing with shading](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/172253/generic-contour-smoothing-with-shading)) that could help me improve my images. Unfortunately, they can only be used with graphics generated by the software itself:

```
ClearAll[smoothCP]
smoothCP = Module[{pr = PlotRange @ #, 
  nF =  Nearest[Join @@ Cases[Normal @ #, Line[a_] :> Transpose[#2 /@ Transpose@a], ∞]]},
  # /. GraphicsComplex[a_, b__] :> GraphicsComplex[ 
    If[Or @@ MemberQ @@@ Thread @ {pr, #}, #, First @ nF @ #] & /@ a, b] ] &;
Row[{p1, smoothCP[p1, GaussianFilter[#, {25, 25}] &]}]
```

I tried to use a PNG image to improve the curves looking for a smooth spline or b-spline.

[image]

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yy0uN.png"]
Row[{img, smoothCP[img, GaussianFilter[#, {25, 25}] &]}]
```

I looked for something on the site, but I didn't find what I wanted.

**Is it possible to obtain a smooth spline curve from PNG images?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Extracting a spline from the image is easiest with `ImageMesh`. I've used the midpoints of the lines on the mesh boundary for the `BSplineCurve` control points.

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yy0uN.png"];
mesh = ImageMesh@img;
midpoints = Midpoint /@ MeshPrimitives[mesh, 1];
Graphics[{Thick, Darker[Red], 
  BSplineCurve[midpoints, SplineClosed -> True]}]
```

[image: bspline from image]

You can also filter the curve to smooth it out, by replacing each point on the spline by the midpoint of its neighbours:

```
(* also try `Partition[points, 3, 1]` here too for a different effect *)
filter[points_] := Midpoint[#[[{1, 3}]]] & /@ Partition[points, 3, 2]
Manipulate[
 Graphics[
  BSplineCurve[Nest[filter, midpoints, k], SplineClosed -> True]]
 , {k, 0, 7, 1}]
```

[image: midpoint filtering]

Comment: I think I will have to create a Midpoint function, because I have version only Mathematica 11 software

Comment: Midpoint[{x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}] := {(x1 + x2)/2, (y1 + y2)/2}

Comment: @flinty are there some commands that we can convert b-spline to  bezier in Mathematica?

Comment: @ABCDEMMM please ask in a new question.