# Improve quality of ComplexPlot contours

Tags: plotting, complex

**Context**

When I plot

```
pl = ComplexPlot[1/(x^2 + 1), {x, -2 - 2 I, 2 + 2 I}, 
  ColorFunction -> {ColorData["RedBlueTones"], "CyclicLogAbsArg"}]
```

I get this image

[image]

which shows some (admittedly minor) defects

[image]

**Question**

> How to improve quality of ComplexPlot contours?

I have tried adding the Options `PlotPoints -> 150, WorkingPrecision -> 40` but it did not improve things.

I have also tried this [postprocessing](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/172395/1089) but it did not work.

Comment: Try cranking up `RasterSize`, e.g. `RasterSize -> 900`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since this option is not in the documentation, @J.M.'s comment should be in an answer:

> Try cranking up `RasterSize`, e.g. `RasterSize -> 900`. – J. M.'s ennui♦ 14 hours ago

```
ComplexPlot[1/(x^2 + 1), {x, -2 - 2 I, 2 + 2 I}, 
 ColorFunction -> {ColorData["RedBlueTones"], "CyclicLogAbsArg"}, 
 RasterSize -> 900]
```

[image: plot]

Crank it up more, if dissatisfied.

One might discover the option by pondering the undocumented things in:

```
ComplexPlot // Options
(*  {..., RasterSize -> Automatic,...}  *)
```

It's a long list, though.

---

Note by J.M.:

The `PlotPoints`/`MaxRecursion` settings do not affect the resolution of the domain coloring plot here. Instead, they only affect the resolution of the boundary (as rendered with `BoundaryStyle`) and mesh (as rendered with `Mesh`/`MeshFunctions`/`MeshStyle`).

`RasterSize` is independent of these, and controls the fineness of the sampling of the domain coloring image itself. It could certainly be argued that it should either be documented, or should at least have a relation with the more natural `PlotPoints` option.