# Do Any of the filter functions perform a LOESS or LOWESS filter?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, filtering

From the [Data Transforms and Smoothing](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/DataTransformsAndSmoothing.html) guide there is a link to the [Linear and Nonlinear Filters](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/LinearAndNonlinearFilters.html) guide. Do any of these filter functions perform a [LOESS or LOWESS filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_regression) on set of paired data?  Searches for "loess" and "lowess" come up empty in *Mathematica* help but things sometimes go by another name. I really prefer the LOWESS filter over the LOESS filter.

If not, is there another function (maybe an image function) or would this have to be coded from scratch?

Some data to demonstrate the smoothing on:

```
dat = {{2.5388, 160}, {1.791, 130}, {2.88673, 140}, {2.05391, 130}, {2.1987,
   130}, {2.22434, 140}, {2.53868, 170}, {2.59566, 150}, {1.68293, 
  130}, {2.32455, 140}, {2.70714, 160}, {2.29725, 140}, {2.26859, 
  140}, {2.59289, 160}, {2.12666, 140}, {2.20377, 130}, {3.14684, 
  150}, {2.34561, 130}, {1.68741, 120}, {2.51823, 130}, {2.8703, 
  160}, {2.94802, 180}, {3.10839, 180}, {3.39548, 170}, {1.38768, 
  81}, {1.76145, 97}, {1.88736, 97}, {1.92727, 102}, {1.8698, 
  102}, {1.6378, 104}, {1.85618, 112}, {1.8413, 112}, {1.83661, 
  119}, {2.1003, 122}, {2.18675, 124}, {2.20111, 127}, {2.23716, 
  127}, {2.65555, 132}, {2.55666, 132}, {2.54618, 137}, {2.7703, 
  142}, {3.06095, 145}, {2.73968, 147}, {2.6985, 147}, {2.93909, 
  152}, {2.839, 152}, {2.9723, 155}, {2.79205, 157}, {2.79859, 
  160}, {3.25364, 168}, {2.72511, 168}, {2.4127, 170}, {3.29402, 
  170}, {3.28745, 170}, {3.06602, 172}, {3.12907, 170}, {3.54607, 
  180}, {2.31484, 140}, {2.8195, 170}, {2.77789, 150}, {2.655, 
  170}, {2.79148, 170}, {1.29638, 78}, {1.47898, 84}, {3.12846, 
  182}, {3.04629, 179}}
```

Comment: An implementation of LOESS is available in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/45524/27951) by [@Rahul](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/484/rahul).

Comment: @MarcoB Thanks, that is interesting.  After reading all the answers there I am thinking that I may be able to do something with `MovingMap` and `LeastSquares` for LOESS.  I really want LOWESS though so I'll see what answers are posted.

Comment: Edmund, could you spell out the difference between LOWESS and LOESS for me, as well as for the good of the question?

Comment: @MarcoB Both use a moving window from left to right across the data. The width of the window varies based on the density of the points in a neighbourhood of the window. At each view a regression is performed and the fitted value of the mid-point of the window is taken as the smoothed point. LOESS does a basic linear regression for each view. LOWESS uses a weighting for the points in the view with points in the centre of the window having greater weight than points near the edge.

Comment: It seems that everyone has a different idea of what the difference between loess and lowess is (and none of them agree with you): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_regression, https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/bioconductor/2003-September/002337.html, http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/lowess-smoothing.html, http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/161069

Comment: @Rahul They seem to agree agree with me. "Local" is a reference to the window. It is in a local area of the data.  From the R documentation:  https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/lowess.html

Comment: I don't think you understood my comment. What does that have to do with the *difference between loess and lowess*? Wikipedia and Mathworks say the difference is between linear and quadratic regression, R and the stats SE answer say the difference is between bivariate and multivariate data, but everyone agrees that both do a local weighting that falls off near the edge of the window, unlike your comment. Anyway, if you're looking for a locally weighted regression, my answer linked by MarcoB *does* do that.

Comment: @Rahul Ah, I see. Yes. My understanding appears to have been incomplete.  Thanks for that.  In the end I prefer the LOWESS as it is better at finding non-linear trends.

Answer (score 8):

I am afraid that this is not really an answer, but a collection of bookmarks for future reference, since this question is bound to come up in searches about LOESS and LOWESS on this site. Here are a few implementations found searching the web:

- [@Rahul](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/484/rahul) has volunteered an implementation in an answer on this site: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/45524/27951
- [@Verbeia](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/8/verbeia) has posted her implementation (developed with David Burmaster of Alceon Corporation) on her web site: http://www.verbeia.com/mathematica/mathecon/othercode.html
- Eric Webb posted an implementation to GitHub: https://github.com/webmonarch/mathematica-loess