# An accumulated moving average

Tags: list-manipulation, probability-or-statistics, algorithm

**1. Problem statement**

In accordance with the standard definitions the inbuilt `MovingAverage`

```
list = {a, b, c, d, e};
n = 3;    
MovingAverage[list, n]
```

{(a + b + c)/3, (b + c + d)/3, (c + d + e)/3}

shortens the original list. But in some cases (f.e. if the values are very similar) it might be desirable to avoid this shortening.

I thought there should be an inbuilt function (variant) which would do this. So I looked at `MovingMap`, `TimeSeries` and related functions, but I didn't find one.

**2. Current solution**

After some struggling with the `Partition` parameters I found the following solution:

```
par = Partition[list, n, 1, -1, {}]
```

{{a}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}, {b, c, d}, {c, d, e}}

```
MapApply[Plus] @ par / Map[Length, par]
```

{a, (a + b)/2, (a + b + c)/3, (b + c + d)/3, (c + d + e)/3}

**3. Other examples**

```
list = {a, b, c, d, e, f};
n = 4;
Plus @@@ # / Map[Length, #] & [Partition[list, n, 1, -1, {}]]
```

{a, (a + b)/2, (a + b + c)/3, (a + b + c + d)/4, (b + c + d + e)/4, (c + d + e + f)/4}

```
list = {a, b};
n = 2;
Plus @@@ # / Map[Length, #] & [Partition[list, n, 1, -1, {}]]
```

{a, (a + b)/2}

**4. Question**

I'm curious to see what alternative solutions would look like

Comment: Once you have `par`, wouldn't `Mean /@ par` achieve the result you seek?

Comment: Oh, yes of course, that's why outside looks are so important :)

Comment: You might consider a more modern approach by using LOESS and/or LOWESS:  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/106126/do-any-of-the-filter-functions-perform-a-loess-or-lowess-filter.  This approach doesn't need to assume equal distances between data points and even allows extrapolation (although there should be some subject matter justification for that).

Comment: It's possible that the reason you haven't found an inbuilt function for doing this is that the correct solution to this issue depends on the nature of your data. For instance, if the data followed an approximately linear trend, the method you've outlined here would give biased results at the end values. In that case, one might be better off running a linear fit through the last available data points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
movingMean = MovingMap[Mean @* DeleteCases[0], #, #2 - 1, 0] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
movingMean[{a, b}, 2]
```

> ```
> {a, (a + b)/2}
> ```

```
movingMean[{a, b}, 1000]
```

> ```
> {a, (a + b)/2}
> ```

```
movingMean[{a, b, c, d, e}, 2]
```

> ```
> {a, (a + b)/2, (b + c)/2, (c + d)/2, (d + e)/2}
> ```

```
movingMean[{a, b, c, d, e}, 3]
```

> ```
> {a, (a + b)/2, 1/3 (a + b + c), 1/3 (b + c + d), 1/3 (c + d + e)}
> ```

```
movingMean[{a, b, c, d, e}, 4]
```

> ```
> {a, (a + b)/2, 1/3 (a + b + c), 1/4 (a + b + c + d), 1/4 (b + c + d + e)}
> ```

**Note:**

We can also use [`TagSetDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagSetDelayed.html) to define a tag that makes `MovingAverage` behave *as if* it accepts `UpTo[_]` as the second argument:

```
$upTo /: MovingAverage[a_, $upTo[n_]] := movingMean[a, n]
```

***Examples:***

```
MovingAverage[{a, b, c, d, e}, $upTo[2]]
```

> ```
> {a, (a + b)/2, (b + c)/2, (c + d)/2, (d + e)/2}
> ```

```
MovingAverage[{a, b, c, d, e}, $upTo[4]]
```

> ```
> {a, (a + b)/2, 1/3 (a + b + c), 1/4 (a + b + c + d), 1/4 (b + c + d + e)}
> ```

Comment: Thank you, kglr, much to learn here

Answer (score 5):

```
movingAverage = 
  ListCorrelate[ConstantArray[1, #2], 
    #, 
   -1, 
    0, 
    #2 &, 
    Mean @* DeleteCases[0] @* List] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
movingAverage[{a, b}, 2]
```

> ```
> {a, (a + b)/2}
> ```

```
movingAverage[{a, b}, 10^5]
```

> ```
> {a, (a + b)/2}
> ```

```
movingAverage[{a, b, c, d, e}, 2]
```

> ```
> {a, (a + b)/2, (b + c)/2, (c + d)/2, (d + e)/2}
> ```

```
movingAverage[{a, b, c, d, e}, 4]
```

> ```
> {a, (a + b)/2, 1/3 (a + b + c), 1/4 (a + b + c + d), 1/4 (b + c + d + e)}
> ```

```
movingAverage[{a, b, c, d, e}, 10]
```

> ```
> {a, (a + b)/2, 1/3 (a + b + c), 1/4 (a + b + c + d),   
>  1/5 (a + b + c + d + e)}
> ```

Answer (score 5):

Using the (still-undocumented) 6th argument of `Partition`:

```
movingPartitionAverage = Partition[##, 1, -1, {}, Mean @* List] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
movingPartitionAverage[{a, b}, 2]
```

> ```
> {a, (a + b)/2}
> ```

```
movingPartitionAverage[{a, b}, 10^5]
```

> ```
> {a, (a + b)/2}
> ```

```
movingPartitionAverage[{a, b, c, d, e}, 2]
```

> ```
> {a, (a + b)/2, (b + c)/2, (c + d)/2, (d + e)/2}
> ```

```
movingPartitionAverage[{a, b, c, d, e}, 4]
```

> ```
> {a, (a + b)/2, 1/3 (a + b + c), 1/4 (a + b + c + d), 1/4 (b + c + d + e)}
> ```

```
movingPartitionAverage[{a, b, c, d, e}, 10]
```

> ```
> {a, (a + b)/2, 1/3 (a + b + c), 1/4 (a + b + c + d),   
>  1/5 (a + b + c + d + e)}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

My attempt is the following:

```
CompleteAdjustedMovingAverage[data_List, n_Integer] := 
Module[{len, partitionSize, start, end, partitions},
len = Length[data];
partitions = Table[partitionSize = Min[n, i, len - i + n];
start = i - partitionSize + 1;
end = i;
data[[start ;; end]], {i, len}];
Mean /@ partitions]
```

Testing `CompleteAdjustedMovingAverage`:

```
CompleteAdjustedMovingAverage[{a, b, c, d, e}, 3]

(*{a, (a + b)/2, 1/3 (a + b + c), 1/3 (b + c + d), 1/3 (c + d + e)}*)
```