# Smoothing ListContourPlot contours for unstructured grids. Part 2

Tags: plotting, interpolation

My question is motivated by the following discussion.

[Smoothing ListContourPlot contours](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45519/smoothing-listcontourplot-contours)

I need to generate **high-quality** contour plots for some property generated on a **non-rectangular grid**. This is how my grid looks like:

[image]

[data set](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hgug54y7jf997kp/data-set?dl=0)

As an example, let's just plot one contour:

```
data = Import["/path/to/file", "Table"];
density = data[[All, {1, 2, 4}]];
crd1 = {0., 1.196175};
crd2 = {0., -3.588525};
cnvtAtoAU = 1.889726;
shift = ((crd1[[2]] - crd2[[2]])/2 - crd1[[2]])*cnvtAtoAU;
data = {# + {0, shift, 0, 0}} & /@ data //. {x_List} :> x;

cntrValue = 0.000006;
intOrder = 3;
pr = {{-7, 7}, {-11, 11}, {0, 1}};

density = data[[All, {1, 2, 4}]];
dencntr = ListContourPlot[density,
InterpolationOrder -> intOrder,
Contours -> {cntrValue},
PlotRange -> pr,
ContourShading -> None,
ContourStyle -> Black,
ImageSize -> 500,
AspectRatio -> 1.47,
MaxPlotPoints -> 150]
```

This produces the following output:

[image]

Observe that at first glance the plot looks OK, but at a closer look it has tiny distortions and artifacts that I want to get rid of. I am OK even if the solution does not perfectly coincide with the current curve as long as it is perfectly smooth. As I said, I need a high-quality plot for illustrative purpose.

[image]

I tried techniques mentioned in the link above. None of them worked for me. I tried playing with `MaxPlotPoints` and `InterpolationOrder`, no success. I also played with `Interpolation` and splines (achieved nothing).

I was also thinking about transforming data to a different system of coordinates and interpolating it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Strongly related: ["Data interpolation and ListContourPlot](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11765/280)." You can also try [Non-Grid Interpolation Package by Yasushi Iwasaki](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/7760/) and [Obtuse Package by Ingolf Dahl](http://www.familydahl.se/mathematica/#Obtuse) for smooth non-grid interpolation.