# Interpolation of ListContourPlot3D, Volumetric data (cube file)

Tags: plotting, matrix, interpolation

I know there are lots of information about this on stack exchange!

[Data interpolation and ListContourPlot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2928/interpolationorder-for-contourplot)

[InterpolationOrder for ContourPlot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11765/data-interpolation-and-listcontourplot)

Unfortunately I was not able to find a proper way to deal with my issue.

I have a Volumetric data which I read from a gaussian [Cube file](http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/cube/) and I can easily Plot it using `ListContourPlot3D` but the plot is not smooth and I can not use the `InterpolationOrder` in `ListContourPlot3D`. I tried interpolating the data and using `SmoothKernelDistribution`, This only works for a data [x,y] Dimension not [x,y,z]. Even then it's super slow though I only need to plot the data range of [-0.2,0.2] so probably I can cut some data and speed up.

My volumetric data is at dimensions [40,40,40], it can have some mixed volumetric shapes, as below. I have attached it as a [wdx file](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=48E6DEE5D6109E04!182387&authkey=!AJ2zGHQ9FvWcQn4&ithint=file%2Cwdx) it's the `Transpose[cubedata, {3, 2, 1}`, so it what would be plotted and can have shapes as below.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A volume of 40x40x40 is small enough that you can do all kinds of things with it. One easy method is to interpolate the volume yourself with a higher interpolation order

```
data = Import["countour.wdx"];
ip = ListInterpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 3];
ContourPlot3D[ip[x, y, z], {x, 15, 25}, {y, 15, 25}, {z, 15, 25}]
```

This already smooths your volume

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Another way from there is to resample parts of the volume from the interpolation function with a higher resolution and apply an additional smoothing filter. But this is for you to decide.

### Edit

> Is there anyway to still speed up the process? maybe cut the data based on my contours. I need to automate the script to work for hundreds of cube files!

Yes, there is. When we look on your data

```
Image[data[[10]]] // ImageAdjust
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

we see, that it is pretty smooth. I would not smooth it further artificially beyond what's happening during interpolation anyway. Therefore, let me give two additional advices:

#### Tune the parameters for the approach I have given

This includes to verify that an interpolation order of 3 is probably not required. Order 2 will be enough and an interpolation function with decreased order will be faster.

More important, you should specify `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion` of your `ContourPlot3D` call so that it is smooth enough, but does not take unnecessary long.

Below you will find an animation that shows you the effect of both parameters. I suggest to use a recursion depth of 1 and use as many plot points as you can live with

[image]

#### Return to `ListContourPlot3D` with a prior resampling

Another way is to restrict your data (you can do that with the first approach too!), because it seems to me that the fun is happening in the center of your volume.

Then you can use `ArrayResample` to create a higher resolution and in the very same step ensure that the new volume is smooth by adjusting the resampling method. In the easiest case this looks like

```
ListContourPlot3D[
 ArrayResample[data[[10 ;; 30, 10 ;; 30, 10 ;; 30]], {50, 50, 50}, 
  Resampling -> "Gaussian"],
 Contours -> {0.01}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Is there anyway to still speed up the process? maybe cut the data based on my contours.
I need to automate the script to work for hundreds of cube files!

Comment: @RaymondGhaffarianShirazi I have added some further information to the end of my answer.

Comment: I get a small issue with scale, I have updated my post, thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry I fixed that, I guess I had to just cheng 10;;30 to 1;;40

Comment: @RaymondGhaffarianShirazi The `[[10;;40]]` operator just selects the center of your volume. If you like to use the complete volume, then you can just use `data` without everything. You should probably resample than to more than `{50,50,50}`..